# Cannot deploy to Azure App Service from VS Code or CLI

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I am able to create a new Azure App Service on my Azure subscription from VS code. If I then try to deploy my python web application to the App Service that I just created I get a "401 - Unauthorized: Access" error. If I logon to the Azure portal I can view my newly created App Service. I can see on the Access Control page that I am listed as a contributor. I am not sure why I can not deploy my code or view files. Does anyone have suggestions as to security settings to check? I need to be able to deploy my code. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

@Kachopsticks, Apologies! If my response is to too late. To benefit the community, sharing the steps that could help isolate such issues:

There is a way to **disable basic auth access** to the WebDeploy port and SCM site with basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies, see if this is the case.

> basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies --parent sites/ --set properties.allow=false

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/deploy-configure-credentials?tabs=cli#webdeploy-and-scm

You could re-download the publish profile from Azure portal, and **import publish** settings in Visual Studio for deployment.

1. In the Azure portal, open the Azure App Service.
2. Go to Get publish profile and save the profile locally.
   A file with a .publishsettings file extension has been generated in the location where you saved it and you may import that in VS and then attempt to re-deploy.

Additionally, Azure App Service supports two types of credentials for local-Git and FTP/S deployment:

`User-level credentials` one set of credentials for the entire Azure account.

*`App-level credentials`* (one set of credentials for each app. It can be used to deploy to that app only) -. They can't be configured manually, but can be reset anytime. For a user to be granted access to app-level credentials via (RBAC), that user must be contributor or higher on the app (including Website Contributor built-in role). Readers are not allowed to publish, and can't access those credentials.